# See who has upvoted as a new privilege

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, voting, upvotes, privileges

I feel that it would be a nice to have feature, since it would encourage people to check profiles of people who have upvoted their posts and therefore build a greater sense of community.

Comment: Voting is meant to be anonymous. This would likely encourage people to go blindly upvote another user as thanks for upvoting them, which is _not_ what we want. We want votes to be on the content, not the user.

Comment: If people want it known that they voted on something, they'll leave comments.

Comment: @resueman Well if that was the case then the "+1" comments should not be discouraged, like they are now

Comment: They aren't discouraged, if they actually contain useful content in addition to the +1.

Comment: Votes are about content, not users.

Comment: SO isn't a social network. The less user-user interaction the better.

Comment: There would be a lot of embarrassment and strife because we could see who is upvoting all the garbage and make nasty comments about them. It's as problematic as showing who has downvoted.

Comment: Before you get bothered by the downvotes, just a heads up that [voting is different on Meta.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-meta) On feature-requests, downvotes often indicate disagreement rather than quality. You're going to see _a lot_ of disagreement here, most likely.

Comment: @KevinB Then why would you have a user profile at all? Why have Q and A history on users profile? Let's do all anonymously! 
Rep what makes SO not only about content but also about users who create it, and if we don't see rep as a bad thing then we should not see user interactions as bad

Comment: @Kendra thanks, I'm not bothered

Comment: The only "sense of community" that one would get from being able to see who voted on what is one that is *very* hostile.  Votes are anonymous for a reason - and that cuts both ways.

Comment: You would be surprised how many people are bothered by the downvotes. Good on you for not being so!

Comment: @Makoto That's why I propose to see *only* upvotes

Comment: Not even then.  People will upvote questions which *genuinely* don't belong here, and it won't take long before people with digital pitchforks come after them.

Comment: What exactly do you expect people to do with this information? (knowing who upvoted your posts) It's actually pretty irrelevant *who* did the upvote.

Comment: Voting is secret, it should stay that way.

Comment: I just don't see any value to this. It isn't a "for fun" thing, it isn't moderation, it doesn't give you useful information, it doesn't help you interact in any way with the people who upvoted you,

Comment: @KevinB Go to their profile and see the Q's and A's of the upvoter. I propose only because it something that I do when I like someones comment, usually there's more stuff *on topic that I'm researching* in persons A's because he happens to be exposed to that topic. In this way I might discover some knowledge on the topic.

Comment: right... but me upvoting one of your posts doesn't in any way indicate that i have any posts that are related to that topic. it simply means i found your question to be of decent or better quality and useful. it doesn't mean i'm interested in or like the question.

Comment: This might be a privilege that requires a lot of rep. THen only seasoned people would use it and will be less likely to upvote-as-a-gratitude.

Comment: @KevinB You are right, there's no guarantee that upvoter would have related posts, but chances are higher that he does when compared to random SO user. It's a probability question (:

Comment: Actually now I see that the problem of discovery is actually meant to be solved by "related posts" pane on the right. I wonder if then using some extra weight of upvoters posts in the algorithm of "related posts" would improve the usefulness  of the pane.

Comment: All the seasoned users are telling you this is a bad idea.  What more will it take for you to see that?

Comment: @Daedalus as per usual, much discussion that leads to no end.

Comment: @TinyGiant Is that supposed to be a reference to something else, or is it a general reference?

Comment: General reference @Daedalus

Comment: @Daedalus Just FYI https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Argumentum_ad_populum

Comment: `I wonder if then using some extra weight of upvoters posts in the algorithm of "related posts" would improve the usefulness of the pane.` Not sure I understand - would you show posts by users who upvoted the question in the "related" pane? Or do you mean something else?

Comment: @Pekka웃 You almost got me right. The way I see this is search the upvoters posts first for signs of "relevance" and then the rest of SO. Additionally the results of the first query would be weighted to have higher chance to get near the top of the rank. Note that this does not allow unrelated upvoter posts to get into the pane.

Comment: @Pekka웃 Please note that this whole idea is based on my personal usage pattern. I don't read all the questions, only read my tags and mostly questions with zero answers that seem feasible for me to solve. THerefor it is only this kind of questions that I ever upvote or answer. And therefore OP of one of those questions browsing my Qs and As could get insights into his problem. Since I assumed everyone does the same as I do, I expect added value for me from knowing who upvoted my Q. And again I'm not inclined to do gratitude upvotes, but I see how someone would, so I agree my feat.req is bad.

Comment: @Hennadii that probably deviates a lot from how most people vote, yeah. Perhaps this old feature request of mine is to your liking? It goes into a *somewhat* similar direction. (Not that it seems very likely to be implemented....) http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/106717/does-so-need-social-networking-features-to-improve-the-experience-for-expert-use

Comment: @HennadiiMadan FYI: My note was not based on how popular your idea is, but how much merit it had to those who used the site for a long period of time(hence 'seasoned').  In any case, this feature request currently, as of the time of this writing, sports a -51 net, and a status-declined tag.  Also, you're the one that brought up seasoned users as an argument; I simply countered it.

Comment: @Daedalus Please don't take this personally. I just wanted to say that your `All the seasoned users are telling you this is a bad idea. What more will it take for you to see that? `  is a classic *ad populum* and  therefore is not a valid argument. I do agree that it's a bad feature request, I just thought that you might be unaware of this logical fallacy and by learning about it you would improve your reasoning in the future.

Comment: @HennadiiMadan I am quite aware of that argument type, but my point isn't about popularity; my point is that you used the existence of seasoned users in your argument, and I pointed out the seasoned users still disagreed with you.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You know, that "privilege" already exists:
It's known as "being a SE dev", and explicitly disabled on their own posts:
[Can admins see who downvoted them? If not, do developers with DB access look it up?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/90758)

> There is a show votes option for developers, but we explicitly disallow it on our own posts -- to reduce any temptation of looking at votes on our own posts.
>
> The intent of the function is to look at voting irregularities at the developer level.
>
> And of course developers have access to the underlying database anyhow, if they really must know.

Regarding showing that to ordinary users, [a *really* bad idea](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/139147):

> If you see person upvoting your post then you will upvote their post.
>
> If you see person downvoting your post then you will downvote their post.
>
> And voting on posts should be democratic, without knowing person who have done it. And mainly based on quality of content

Even if *you personally* would refrain (most of the time, giving you the benefit of the doubt), it's well-known we *already* have trouble with such patterns.

Answer (score 0):

To summarize the discussion: It is a bad idea since there are concerns that people would do  mutual upvotes as favours. Although it is not guaranteed to happen here on SO, there's ample evidence that this happens in social networks, so I am inclined to agree.

The (perceived by me) benefits of what I was proposing to some extent could be achieved by incorporating info on upvoters in the algorithm for "related posts" pane.

Thank everyone for the discussion.